# "Necessary condition for lpf to lpf transformation is that a magnitude response must keep its original values at $\omega=0$ and $\omega=\pi$"?

Tags: digital-filters

"Necessary condition for lpf to lpf transformation is that a magnitude response must keep its original values at $\omega=0$ and $\omega=\pi$"?

Why is it so?

But does that not essentially read that the cutoff ought to stay the same? Even though one wants to transform a lpf with cutoff $\omega_c$ to another with cutoff $\omega'_c$. Then why this requirement?

Comment: Why do you interpret that as saying that the cutoff must stay the same? It's only the values at the extremes of the filter response that need to stay constant.

Comment: @MBaz So the constraint reads that the filter shape stays the same? E.g. if magnitude is 1 at 0 and 0 at $\pi$, then it's a lowpass? So the new filter should also have this property, for it to be lowpass?

Comment: Yeah, a very general definition of an LPF is that its response is 1 at frequency 0 and 0 at frequency $\pi$. But note that you can have that general shape and still have an arbitrary cutoff frequency.